# Is there a way to change only the 'Question' label and keep the same 'Answer' options for a quiz app?

Tags: swift, xcode

```html
//This is the code of my QuestionViewController. I will provide the codes of my other view controller and class below as well

import UIKit

class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    struct currentAnswers{
        static var currentAnswers = [Answer]()
        
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var singleStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleButton4: UIButton!
    
    //My new single stack view
    
    @IBOutlet weak var SecondSingleStack: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton4: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rangedStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rangedLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rangedLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rangedSlider: UISlider!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var questionProgressView: UIProgressView!
    
    var questions: [Question] = [
        Question(text: "Little interest or pleasure in doing things?",
                 type: .single,
                 answers: [
                    Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A),
                    Answer(text: "Several Days", type: .B),
                    Answer(text: "More than half of the days", type: .C),
                    Answer(text: "Nearly everyday", type: .D)
        ]),
        
        Question(text: "Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless?",
                 type: .single,
                 answers: [
                    Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A),
                    Answer(text: "Several Days", type: .B),
                    Answer(text: "More than half of the days", type: .C),
                    Answer(text: "Nearly everyday", type: .D)
            ]),
        
        Question(text: "If you checked off any problems, how difficult have these problems made it for you at work/home/or with other people?",
                 type: .ranged,
                 answers: [
                    Answer(text: "Not difficult at all", type: .A),
                    Answer(text: "Somewhat difficult", type: .B),
                    Answer(text: "Very difficult", type: .C),
                    Answer(text: "Extremely difficult", type: .D)
            ])
    ]

    var questionIndex = 0
    var answersChosen: [Answer] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
    }
    
    @IBAction func singleAnswerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let currentAnswers = questions[questionIndex].answers
        
        switch sender {
        case singleButton1:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[0])
        case singleButton2:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[1])
        case singleButton3:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[2])
        case singleButton4:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[3])
        default:
            break
        }
        
        nextQuestion()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func secondSinglePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
        let currentAnswers = questions[questionIndex].answers
        
        switch sender {
        case secondButton1:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[0])
        case secondButton2:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[1])
        case secondButton3:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[2])
        case secondButton4:
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[3])
        default:
            break
        }
        
        nextQuestion()
            
            
        }
        
    
    
    @IBAction func rangedAnswerButtonPressed() {
        let currentAnswers = questions[questionIndex].answers
        let index = Int(round(rangedSlider.value * Float(currentAnswers.count - 1)))
        
        answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[index])
        
        nextQuestion()
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        singleStackView.isHidden = true
    
        rangedStackView.isHidden = true
        
        let currentQuestion = questions[questionIndex]
        let currentAnswers = currentQuestion.answers
        let totalProgress = Float(questionIndex) / Float(questions.count)
        
        navigationItem.title = "Question #\(questionIndex+1)"
        questionLabel.text = currentQuestion.text
        questionProgressView.setProgress(totalProgress, animated: true)
        
        switch currentQuestion.type {
        case .single:
            updateSingleStack(using: currentAnswers)

        case .ranged:
            updateRangedStack(using: currentAnswers)
            
        }
    }
    
    func updateSingleStack(using answers: [Answer]) {
        singleStackView.isHidden = false
        singleButton1.setTitle(answers[0].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton2.setTitle(answers[1].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton3.setTitle(answers[2].text, for: .normal)
        singleButton4.setTitle(answers[3].text, for: .normal)
    }
 
    
    func updateSecondSingleStack(using answers: [Answer]){
        
        SecondSingleStack.isHidden = false
        secondButton1.setTitle(answers[0].text, for: .normal)
        secondButton2.setTitle(answers[1].text, for: .normal)
        secondButton3.setTitle(answers[2].text, for: .normal)
        secondButton4.setTitle(answers[3].text, for: .normal)
    }
    
    
    
    func updateRangedStack(using answers: [Answer]) {
        rangedStackView.isHidden = false
        rangedSlider.setValue(0.5, animated: false)
        rangedLabel1.text = answers.first?.text
        rangedLabel2.text = answers.last?.text
    }
    
    func nextQuestion() {
        questionIndex += 1
        
        if questionIndex < questions.count {
            updateUI()
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ResultsSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ResultsSegue" {
            let resultsViewController = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
            resultsViewController.responses = answersChosen
        }
    }

}





//This is my QuestionData class

import Foundation

struct Question {
    var text: String
    var type: ResponseType
    var answers: [Answer]
}

enum ResponseType {
    case single, ranged
}

struct Answer {
    var text: String
    var type: CaseScore
}

enum CaseScore: Character {
    case A = "", B = "", C = "", D = ""
    
    var definition: String {
        switch self {
        case .A:
            return "Not at all - Should be replaced with percentage and Advice"
        case .B:
            return "Several Days"
        case .C:
            return "More than half of the days"
        case .D:
            return "Nearly everyday"
        
        }
    }
}





//And finally this is my ResultsViewController

import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var resultAnswerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultDefinitionLabel: UILabel!
    var responses: [Answer]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        calculatePersonalityResult()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func calculatePersonalityResult() {
        var frequencyOfAnswers: [CaseScore:Int] = [:]
        let responseTypes = responses.map { $0.type }
        
        for response in responseTypes {
            frequencyOfAnswers[response] = (frequencyOfAnswers[response] ?? 0) + 1
        }
        
        let mostCommonAnswer = frequencyOfAnswers.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }.first!.key
        
        resultAnswerLabel.text = "You are a \(mostCommonAnswer.rawValue)!"
        resultDefinitionLabel.text = mostCommonAnswer.definition
    }
}
```

I am developing a Personality Test IOS app for school on XCode and I have done it similar to the IBooks 'App Development with Swift' book, Guided Project: Personality Quiz, page 398.  Moreover, my goal is a bit different. I have 10 questions for the quiz and each of the questions will require answer options like: (A. Not at all, B. Several Days, C. More than half o the days, D. Nearly every day).  The way mentioned in the book is for different types of questions with different answer options.

The code provided is an example of the 2 questions and answers, but there will be more to come if I complete the 10 questions the same way.

```
var questions: [Question] = [
    Question(text: "Little interest or pleasure in doing things?",
             type: .single,
             answers: [
                Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A),
                Answer(text: "Several Days", type: .B),
                Answer(text: "More than half of the days", type: .C),
                Answer(text: "Nearly everyday", type: .D)
        ]),

    Question(text: "Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless?",
             type: .single,
             answers: [
                Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A),
                Answer(text: "Several Days", type: .B),
                Answer(text: "More than half of the days", type: .C),
                Answer(text: "Nearly everyday", type: .D)
        ]),
```

I would like to know another way to reduce amount of code and use the same answer options for all questions, without affecting accuracy of choice for each question.  Please let me know if you know how to do it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Make one struct for the answer and pass this to all questions have the same answers option

Comment: How would this update the value of each button of the answer options? Is there any other step or change needed? I have done it the way above

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var answers = [Answer]()
answers.append(Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A))
answers.append(Answer(text: "Several Days", type: .B))
answers.append(Answer(text: "More than half of the days", type: .C))
answers.append(Answer(text: "Not at all", type: .A))
```

And (How to use)

```
var questions: [Question] = [
    Question(text: "Little interest or pleasure in doing things?",
             type: .single,
             answers: answers),

    Question(text: "Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless?",
             type: .single,
             answers: answers),
```

The basic idea is to create a variable which holds the array of `Answer` and then use it in your questions.

Comment: Thank you Sahil! I have tried it but it did not actually work directly.  The other methods could not access the answers array.  I have tried creating a static var in a struct for that but I got some errors.  Maybe because of the way my code is written? I will share with you the code if you could check it please and tell me where to make the additions.. Much appreciated!

Comment: ^ Thank you Sahil! I have tried it but it did not actually work directly.